# Spyder not recognizing splinter

Tags: python-3.4, spyder, splinter

Though splinter is installed on my Windows Vista, spyder gives an error when I import it.

- When I import in windows command prompt, it successfully imports & also shows path to the init file.
- Have added explicit path in PYTHONPATH Manager of Spyder and Updated module list. Yet, did not help.
- Have checked my PATH environment variable. It contains the path to Python, Python/Scripts & Python/Lib/site-packages. PATH contains no spaces and PATH is indeed named as PATH & not as Path (probably thats why able to import successfully via command prompt)
- When I try to install splinter again (just to confirm if it exists or not), pip says it already exists. When I try to upgrade, pip says it is already up-to-date
- Have read lots & lots of articles on stackoverflow & across the web, but no solution helped.
- Spyder recognizes other packages like os, numpy, etc.

Had run this code successfully on a temporary testing machine. Now trying to run on my system and its failing with error `ImportError: No module named 'splinter'`

*Python ver. 3.4; Spyder ver. 3.4*

Hoping for a solution...

Complete trackeback:

> runfile('E:/Rampy/DS/Python/Code/AGMARK.py', wdir='E:/Rampy/DS/Python/Code')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>     runfile('E:/Rampy/DS/Python/Code/AGMARK.py', wdir='E:/Rampy/DS/Python/Code')
>
> File "C:\Users\ramprasad.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
>      execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\ramprasad.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 48, in execfile
>      exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "E:/Rampy/DS/Python/Code/AGMARK.py", line 8, in 
>      from splinter import Browser
>
> ImportError: No module named 'splinter'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. So, I could make it work with a work-around.

Inspite of adding C:\Python34 & its Lib (site-packages) folder to PATH environment variable and Spyder's Python Path Manager, it failed to recognize splinter package while running the code in Spyder. So, I copied & pasted Splinter (followed by Selenium) package-folders from C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages (location where PIP installed the packages) to `C:\Users\ramprasad.g\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` (Anaconda's package location which alone Spyder seems to recognize) and boom! It started working!